# Injecting sudo su with aliases

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc

I'm wondering if there is a way to inject alias when you switch to root profile with sudo.

What I have in mind is this:

```
sshLogin@linuxVM /home/sshLoginUser/> sudo su -x "alias goHome='cd /home/sshLoginUser/'"
root@linuxVM /home/OtherDir/> goHome
root@linuxVM /home/sshLoginUser/>
```

I am using a VM box on cloud to setup and run some operations, and I want to eventually add more alias for repetitive tasks.

Ideally, I would like to `sudo su` and `source` on a file which contains my collection of aliases and functions.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand, that `sudo` does not do shell expansion; it runs a command. There are probably two solutions for what you would want to do, each with there own advantages/disadvantages:

1 `alias hop='sudo id'`: let the `sudo` be part of the alias or

2 `sudo -s` (without command), which starts an interactive shell and reads `/root/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tom@alarm ~]$ sudo -i
[root@alarm ~]# tail -n 1 .bashrc
alias goHome="cd /home/$SUDO_USER"
[root@alarm ~]# goHome
[root@alarm tom]# pwd
/home/tom
[root@alarm tom]#
```

If the "built-in" env vars are not sufficient for your cases, you can also make sudo preserve some custom ones. For example:

```
CERTAINFILE="/home/$USER/different_name" sudo -i --preserve-env=CERTAINFILE
```